# Magento 2 installation trouble

Tags: magento2.2

I can not install magento 2.2.1 at my server-ip (not point to dns yet). I am running centos 7 with cwp (centos web panel), apache 2.4.9, php 7.0.24, mariadb 10.1.29. I already have tried at test environment with virtualbox, it worked perfect, even with nginx.

Now At this time at webserver, I have tried different methods without luck, like:

1.- fix permission to magento installation directory /home/username/public_html/

2.- with and without nginx

3.- installed by command line

4.- also I have read different topics, all those are about after install, I am stuck at installation procedure, It is suppose to see web installation wizard at http://server-ip/ (or http://server-ip/setup ) , however It does not show up, I just can see http test page.

5.- Also I have checked mod_rewrite and .htaccess and ServerName.

As far as I can see, In virtualbox server ip and shared ip are different and I used Nat-ed option. At server production server ip and shared ip are the same and I have not used Nat-ed.

Any advice?

Comment: I resolved using this tutorial https://in.godaddy.com/help/preview-your-website-using-host-files-3354 . It was a dns name trouble.